# Is there a way to track changes to the DOM and CSS Inspector in developer tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools, safari-web-inspector

When you make changes to the DOM or CSS when using the developer tools of a browser, is there a way to view all the changes you have made in one place?

I can't see a way to do this in Safari or Firefox Developer Edition. If possible, would it require an external plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you can do this in Chrome for local files.

The [Chrome DevTools Setup Guide](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow) explains how to do this.